# Use of delete[] but bytes are definitely lost, why?

Tags: c++

To explain my issue, this is minimalist main.cc:

```
#include "./main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *buffer = new char[12];
    char *output = new char[12];
    FILE *input  = fopen("file.test", "r");

    while ( read_stdin(buffer, 12, input, output) ) {
        // Operations on output
        // (...)
    }

    fclose(input);
    delete[] output; output = 0;
    delete[] buffer; buffer = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

And main.h:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

inline bool read_stdin(char *tmp_buffer, const size_t &len, FILE *input, char *&output) {
    output = fgets(tmp_buffer, len, input);
    if ( output != NULL ) {
        char *lf = strchr(output, '\n');
        if ( lf != NULL ) {
            *lf = '\0';
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function read_stdin() can read from STDIN, it explains its name.

Well, all work as expected, but valgrind tells me things like:

```
==6915== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==6915==    at 0x4C29527: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6915==    by 0x4008A2: main (main.cc:6)
```

I compile as `g++ -O0 -g main.cc -o test`

I understand that these 12 bytes are "output", but why is there some bytes lost? I use of delete[], even if there is nothing from STDIN or input, output will be NULL right?

I misunderstand why there are still these 12 bytes, where am I wrong?

Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT**

Thanks to Vaughn Cato, Dietmar Kühl and Richard J. Ross III, I changed lines:

```
output = fgets(tmp_buffer, len, input);
    if ( output != NULL ) {
```

to

```
if ( fgets(output, len, input) != NULL ) {
```

Comment: Could be a valgrind bug, but your code looks correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've replaced `output` with a different pointer, so you aren't deleting the same thing you allocated:

```
output = fgets(tmp_buffer, len, input);
```

I'm not sure why `read_stdin` has the `output` parameter.  If you just need to check the result of fgets, then you could use a local variable instead:

```
inline bool read_stdin(char *tmp_buffer, const size_t &len, FILE *input) {
    char *output = fgets(tmp_buffer, len, input);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII And it wasn't passed the same pointer, was it?

Comment: My mistake is the prototype of `read_stdin(..., char *&output)`?

Comment: @Richard J.Ross III: Indeed. So `output` get replaced by `tmp_buffer` or by null.

Comment: Well, since it's a reference to a pointer, once you change `output` in your function, you're changing what `output` was pointing to outside the function and therefore `delete[] output;` isn't releasing the right memory.

Comment: @Tiger-222: I'm not sure what the `output` parameter is for.

Comment: @Tiger-222: Passing a reference to the pointer causes the pointer in the calling function to be changed, too.